# Is it possible to make rndc always validate on reload?

Tags: bind, rndc

I've noticed that on some occasions, when I run `rndc reload foobar.com`, it'll validate the domain -- it'll give me an error if there is one, for example:

```
rndc: 'reload' failed: multiple RRs of singleton type
```

... or ...

```
rndc: 'reload' failed: not a valid number
```

... which is good.

However, some times, `rndc` will say:

```
rndc: zone reload queued
```

... and the error will only be logged.

Is it possible to have rndc always validate on reload? The reason being, when my application updates a zone, it runs rndc to reload the zone and assumes that it will fail if the zone is invalid. However, it only does this some times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
named-checkzone
```

To expand on that answer a bit: I'm not aware of a way, via rndc, to force an immediate reload.  But by working named-checkzone into your reload operation, as with a small script or alias, you can accomplish your goal.

Comment: Yeah, I think I'll change the app so it calls this first. Thanks.

Comment: Solved my problem!

Comment: `named-checkconf -zj` may be helpful for a broader check (validates config + zones found from config).